# What to use for this amount of data in an iOS app (plist JSON or XML)?

Tags: xml, xcode, plist

I'm building a simple app that is going to list & provide descriptions for places within a town, and I'm looking for clarification on the best way to supply the data to the app (too much data for a plist?)

- It's static data (I intend to bundle it with the app)
- The data must be loaded dynamically (so that I can reuse the app for multiple towns)
- Yes, the data will need to be updated, but very infrequently (perhaps on a yearly basis)
- At the maximum the app may list up to 300 places (each description will comprise of 3 or 4 small paragraphs of text - maybe 60 words in total, so in my eyes a relatively small amount of data)

**My question is**: Is a plist appropriate for that amount of data or should I be looking at JSON, XML or some other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer that you should use JSON file in the bundle and when you need this data, read the JSON file and convert it to NSDictionary and use it. 
It's prefer in a way that it will save lot of you time to create a plist file, coz when you read this JSON file using `NSJSONSerialization` or any library it work convert the JSON into `NSDictionary/NSArray`

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use a plist file (that actually is an xml file). Mainly for 2 reasons:

1. the sdk provides convenient methods to read the plist into NSDictionary/NSArray;
2. Xcode makes easy to edit it with plist, xml and source editors.